# Google Earth GEWindow::blur() events in Chrome?

Tags: focus, blur, google-earth-plugin

According to the bug tracker, this should be fixed: https://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?id=108

My code in the `mouseup` handler for a Google Earth object:

```
setTimeout(_.bind(function(){
    $('#takecontrol').focus();
    this.googleEarthObj.getWindow().blur();
}, this), 1);
```

This works in Firefox, but it doesn't appear to be working properly in Chrome. Has anyone found a workaround?

Comment: Thanks for asking the question. I'm also encountering the same problem. By any chance you got this resolved? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @changey I'm sorry, but I can't remember what I did to resolve this or dig up the old code. I believe I just gave up on it and re-designed the page so that I didn't need to use the blur event.